# How to make my code break out of loop and actually detect a certain input

Tags: python

I am doing a basic Python assessment on a password vault but am getting errors that I can't seem to solve myself. and btw guys I didn't come here for a grammar and punctuation lesson, so if you are just here to edit my question and not offer any assistance please dont bother.

For example, in this part of the code I want the user to input 1 or 2, and if he selects 1 it asks him to log in, while if he selects 2 it asks him to register. But at the moment it is completely ignoring the parameters and accepting anything.

Another problem is that when the user enters the valid password, instead of just stopping at password correct, it for some reason re-asks "what is your username."

````
   while True: 
        login_orsignup1 = input('''Press 
1) to Log in
2) to register a new account
''')
        if login_orsignup1 != 1:
            while True: 
                username = input('''What is your,
Username: ''')
                if input_username == username:
                    l_p = input('''What is your password ''')

                    while True:
                        if l_p == input_lockerpassword:
                            print("Password Correct")
                            break
login_originup1()   
----------------------------------------------------------#Full code begins now


l_p = ""
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print('''Welcome to password Locker, a place where you can 
store all your passwords to easily enter your precious accounts without
hassle.''')
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print('''First lets make an account,''')

while True:
    first_name = input('''What is your first name? 
''')
    if first_name.isdigit():  #isdigit, detects if there
        print("Please enter a valid answer, No nubers shoud be present")
    elif first_name == "":
        print("Please enter an answer")
         #the continue code skips the boundries within the loop                                                               and carries on with the connected program until it is succesfully met        

    else:
        break #the break loop exits the current loop and continues with                                                               the next programes following it

while True:
        sur_name = input('''What is your surname?
''')
        if sur_name.isdigit():  #isdigit detects if the
            print("No numbers")
        elif sur_name == "":
            print("Please enter an answer")
             #the continue code skips the boundries within the loop                                                               and carries on with the connected program until it is succesfully met         
        else:
            break

print('''------------------------------------------------------------------------''')
print('''Welcome, {} {} 
what would you like your username to be, it should be something 
memorable and no longer than fifteen characters long, '''.format(first_name, sur_name))
while True:
        input_username = input("")
        if 0 < len(input_username) < 16:
                print('''Nice, username''')
                break
        elif input_username == "":
            print("Please enter an answer")

        else:
            print('''Your username should be a maximum of 15 charecters, ''')
print('''-------------------------------------------------------------------------''')
while True:
    input_lockerpassword = input('''Now it's time to setup a password for your locker, It should be between 4 
and 10 charecters long,  
''')
    if len(input_lockerpassword) > 4 and len(input_lockerpassword) < 11:
        print('''{}, is locked in thanks for joining Password Locker'''.format(input_lockerpassword)) 
        break
    else:
        print("It should be between 4 and 10 charecters long!")
print('''
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------''')
def login_originup1():
    print(''' Welcome to password vault, You can either login or create a New account''')
    while True: 
        login_orsignup1 = input('''Press
1) to Log in
2) to register a new account
''')
        if login_orsignup1 != 1:
            while True: 
                username = input('''What is your,
Username: ''')
                if input_username == username:
                    l_p = input('''What is your password ''')

                    while True:
                        if l_p == input_lockerpassword:
                            print("Password Correct")
                            break
login_originup1()```
````

Comment: Please indent your code correctly

Comment: @Hugo Delahaye what do you mean, i get no indent error

Comment: @roobo Indent your code so that it displays correctly here on this site, no one here can see your editor, that is what "Please indent your code correctly" means.

Comment: At the end of the file, it looks like an infinite loop on `while True:  if l_p == input_lockerpassword...` if the password doesn't match. I think you should remove that `while True` or move it one line earlier.

Comment: @ Ken Shirriff , hi thanks for your help how can i remove the while true, loop connected to it, it says syntax error?

Comment: Editing questions is an important part of this site. People are doing you a favor and improving your question, which in turn will help you get better answers. It will also potentially make your question more valuable to future users.

Comment: @ Mark Meyer Yes i get that but when 40 people have viewed it and 7 out of 8 people have requested an edit, it kind of gets annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all, you should know that the [input() function returns a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) and, as such, your first condition : `if login_orsignup1 != 1` will always be true, because the string object `'1'` isn't equal to the int object `1`. As for why you get asked again for the user after having a good password, that is because the `break` statement only breaks from the current loop. So you only break of this loop to get back at the start of your username verification loop. I would suggest a cleaner implementation like so :

```
    # login or sign-up loop
    while True: 
        login_orsignup1 = input(" Press \n1) to Log in \n2) to register a new account")
        # you can have the input result in a variable like so, if you want to use it later on
        if login_orsignup1 == "1": # you said '1' was for login, right?
            # or you can test this directly in your if statement 
            # if it is only needed for this condition
            while input("What is your username: ") != username: 
                print("Incorrect username")

            # same thing for password, but could be implemented another way if you 
            # don't want to loop until the user gets the correct password
            while input("What is your password: ") != input_lockerpassword:
                print("Incorrect password for this username")

            # your code gets here only if the user entered the right credentials
            # so you can now break of the login or sign-up loop
            break
        elif login_orsignup1 == "2":
            # code for registration here
```

This could be good enough for a simple thing. I would recommend designing this console program by following concepts of a state-machine and adding more code at each step to handle cases like going back one step or back at the start.

Hope this helps

Comment: hi your answer solbved my problem, but still am wondering how it works, as by looking at it, it looks like while username = username, print("incorrect username")

Comment: @roobo hey, glad it worked. The `while` loop is using the `!=` operator, which is the operator for "not equal to". So the statement `input("What is your username: ") != username` actually verifies if the username given as input is different than the one saved. So, if you enter an incorrect username, the statement will be true and "Incorrect username" will be printed out and the loop will then again go back to the `input("What is your username: ") != username` statement (and ask the user for the input again).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your `login_originup1` function you are making three While loops that the program can't escape from in your function you are asking `if login_orsignup1 != 1`
without an else statement so if the user wanted to login he would press input in "1" then the program will say that

`"1" =! 1` is false

it will look for an else statement But not find one so it will go back to the start of the loop and ask the user to input again. this is it for the First Loop.

Now if the user Inputs in "2" (which means that the user wants to register) it will make him log-in because:

`"2" =! 1`is true

and will continue to the next while loop in here you will be asking for the username and the user will give the username. Now this is it for the Second Loop

we now go to the last loop where you ask for the Password and the User Will give the Password. The program Will either 1. say that it was false and ask for the password again or 2. it will accept the password and Break the While loop.  Now this is it for the Third Loop

so why is it asking me for the Username Because the break statement breaks only the while loop it is in so that break statement broke only the third while loop and was back to the Second Loop which the Second Loop will bring us back into the Third Loop again

so how to fix this?

simple like this:

```
def login_originup1():
    print('Welcome to password vault, You can either login or create a New account')

    while True: 
        login_orsignu = input('Press\n1) to Log in\n2) to register a new account\n')
        loopBreaker = 0
        if loopBreaker:
            break
        if int(login_orsignu) != 1:
            while True: 
                if loopBreaker:
                    break
                username = input('What is your,\nUsername:')
                if input_username == username:
                    l_p = input('What is your password ')
                    while True:
                        if loopBreaker:
                            break
                        if l_p == input_lockerpassword:
                            print("Password Correct")
                            loopBreaker = 1
                            break
```

Comment: thanks for your help, When i input 1 or two it repeats the question and dosnt carry on

Comment: you have to change the if statement from "if login_orsignup1 != 1" too "if int(login_orsignup1) != 1"

Comment: the login_orsignup is my function, and do i replace the loopBreaker with my variables or leave them like that?

Comment: dude you named your function just like you input that is why it is complicated. Ok you see my second If Statement you see how I took the Input Variable and enclosed it in an Int() function. Thats because even if the user inputs in "1" it will be consider as a string and not a number so you have to make sure that you change the value of you input by using the function Int().